# Scalable elasticsearch module with spring data elasticsearch possible?

Tags: spring, elasticsearch, design-patterns, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am working on designing a scalable service(springboot) using which data will be indexed to elastic search.

**Use case:**

My application uses 6 databases(mySql) having same schema. Each database caters to specific region. 
 I have a micro service that connects to all these dbs and indexes data from specific tables to elasicsearch server(v6.8.8) in similar fashion having 6 elasticsearch indexes one for each db.
`Quartz jobs` are employed for this purpose and `RestHighLevelClient`. Also there are delta jobs running each second to look for changes using audit and indexes.

Current problem:

1. Current design is not scalable -  one service doing all the work(data loading, mapping, upsert in bulk). Because indexing is done through quarts jobs, scaling services(running multiple instances) will run the same job multiple times.
2. No failover - Looking for a distributed elasticsearch nodes and indexing data to both nodes. How to do this efficiently.

I am considering `spring data elasticsearch` to index data sametime when it is going to be persisted to db.

Does it offer all features ? I use :

- Elasticsearch right from installing template to creating/deleting indexes, aliases.
- Blue/green deployment - index to non-active nodes and change the aliases.
- bulk upsert, querying, aggregations..etc

Any other solutions are welcome. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Your one of the use case is to move data from DB (Mysql) to ES in a scalable manner. It is basically a CDC (Change data capture) pipeline.

You can use [kafka-connect](https://docs.confluent.io/3.0.0/connect/intro.html) framework for the same.

**The flow should be like:**

1. Read Mysql Transaction logs **=>** Publish the data to Kafka (This can be accomplished using [Debezium Source Connector](https://iamninad.com/how-debezium-kafka-stream-can-help-you-write-cdc/))
2. Consume data from Kafka **=>** Push it to Elastic Search (This can be accomplished using [ES-SYNC Connector](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-elasticsearch/index.html))

**Why to use the framework ?**

1. Using connect framework data can be read directly from Mysql Transaction logs without writing code.
2. Connect framework is a distributed & Scalable system
3. It will reduce the load on your database as you now don't need to query your database for detecting any changes
4. Easy to set-up

Comment: Thanks @Sahil Gupta for the solution. Looks promising. I had another doubt though. Our ES indices wont last for more than 8 days. There is a need for whole db reindexing. Here we dont have any event triggered, so how would I go for reindexing using Karka-connect.

Comment: If the use case is to clear index then why to reindex complete data again?

Comment: As per the policy set at my organization, ES indices needs to be deleted every 8 days. Hence the requirement for reindex came into picture. Once the indices are deleted, we need to create new indexes and index whole table data again. We need to capture on demand changes as well.

Comment: One option in that case is create another connector with different identifier, and enable with snapshot mode.